# Page-down/page-up from the keyboard in Preview.app's continuous scroll?

Tags: keyboard, macos, preview

How do you page-down/page-up in Preview.app's continuous scroll mode? When I hit the page-down button on my keyboard, instead of showing me the next page worth of the PDF, it scrolls me to a new page -- that is, I'd like to see the bottom of page one when I hit page-down, but I get page two instead. No other app I've ever used has this behavior. (I'm using Mavericks. Would like the old Snow Leopard functionality!)

Comment: I also have the same question.  I noticed that if you're not at the top of the page, page up/page down moves 1 screen instead of 1 page.  But when the top of the page lines up with the top of the window, page up/page down just moves to the top of the prev/next page.